# Can an application that uses a storyboard be deployed in an iPhone not running on iOS 5

Tags: ios, version, storyboard

The storyboard is a very powerful and easier way to build iOS apps. But I just want to know if  apps made using them will work on iOS earlier than 5.0. For example, will it work on iPhone original or iPhone 3G
 If it will not, to be able to run it on all iOS versions, do I just use the old method (I mean nibs and programmatically creating MVC)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is: **no**.

Storyboard is a iOS 5 or later technology. It will work on any device running iOS5. Apps using UIStoryboard will not work on iOS 4 or iOS 3.

You should think of it in terms of iOS versions and not physical devices, although, obviously, any device **not** capable of running iOS 5 won't be able to use UIStoryboard, either.

Comment: I know it's the matter of iOS versions but not the device. I just wrote iPhone original and 3g because they don't support iOS 5.